# Is $vw$ substitutable for $v$ in the following expression?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Is $vw$ substitutable for $v$ in the expression $∃y(x < vx ⇒ (∃w(w < v)))$ ? The new expression would be:
$$∃y(x < vwx ⇒ (∃w(w < vw)))$$
My answer would be yes, because, at least from a mathematical standpoint, the meaning of the expression remains unchanged. Is this a good way of justifying it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider the defintion of *substitutable for* (clause for quantifiers):

> term $t$  is *substitutable* for $x$ in $\varphi$ iff [...] $\varphi := ∀yα$ [$∃yα$]  and either: a) $x$ is not free in $\varphi$ or: b) $y$ does not occur in $t$ and $t$ is substitutable for $x$ in $α$.

Consider the formula: $∃w(w < v)$. If we substitute $w$ in place of $v$ what we get will be $∃w(w < w)$ and thus it is not true in general that " the meaning of the expression remains unchanged".

The above substitution does not satisfies the clause of *substitutable for* because with $vw$ as $t$ the variable $w$ of the $∃w$ quantifier occurs in $t$.

Comment: So is it because of the $w$? Like, if it had been $vy$ for example, instead of $vw$, would it have been subtitutable?

Comment: @grokestray - No, for the same reason: the definition is not satisfied.

Comment: Avoid convoluted examples... Consider $\exists n (n < m)$ and the result of replacing $m$ with $n$.